# Check if image edge is smooth

Tags: python, opencv

I have a small image as defined below and I want to check if the edges of the image are smooth, like a leaf for example. How to do that?

```
sImg = cv2.imread("source", 0)
```

Sample of a smooth edge image is shown below.

[image]

I am thinking of doing a template matching, but I think there's a way that I can do this other than template matching.

Comment: Please post an example image and describe the problem in relation to the image. Define smooth -- to what degree?

Comment: Yes as @fmw42 said you need to add some example pictures to your post and you should be more clear to explain your exact problem.

Comment: I added image now.

Comment: Please define smooth in the sense you are trying to determine.